# Centering an icon to text?

Tags: html, css, icons

Help! I can't figure out how to align the icon with the text in the navbar without it pushing the rest of the text in the div down.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hungus Bungus <i class="material-icons">polymer</i></a>
    </div> <!-- other divs are closed below -->
```

[image]

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/hungus--bungus/pen/rdgEze?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex on `.navbar-brand` as follows:

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  
}
```

Comment: YES! Ahh, thank you so much. I had a similar issue on my previous site for the class and used some janky poor coding to hide it.